# Attribute Value must be a Constant in Retrofit Api Interface

Tags: java, android, gradle, retrofit

I am trying to hide my API Key and therefore am setting up my Retrofit  Api Interface as such:

> ```
> public interface ApiInterface {
>     @GET("?api_key=" + popularmovies.name.com.popularmovies.BuildConfig.TMD_API_KEY + "&language=en-US")
>     Call<Movies> getImages();
> }
> ```

However, I am receiving an error "Attribute value must be a constant." Is there a way to resolve and access this String?

---

**UPDATE**: Here is a second try:

```
private static final String API_KEY = popularmovies.troychuinard.com.popularmovies.BuildConfig.TMD_API_KEY;


public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("?language=en-US")
    Call<Movies> getImages(@Query("api_key") API_KEY);
}
```

**UPDATE**: Here is a third try:

Below is the logging I am seeing as the URL making the request, as can be seen the API Key is now at the end of the URL which is incorrect syntax:

> 06-10 18:41:33.212 4969-4993/? D/OkHttp: <-- 401 Unauthorized http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?language=en-US&api_key=?api_key%3D09b0a9a9d5d9ddee2b3bc69e78b02457 (592ms)
>       Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Comment: After somebody has answered your question, do not replace the entire contents of the question. This makes the answer useless. Instead, edit the question and add more material to it, such as showing a second attempt at the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
@GET("/rest/of/your/path/here?language=en-US")
Call<Movies> getImages(@Query("api_key") apiKey);
```

where you pass in `popularmovies.name.com.popularmovies.BuildConfig.TMD_API_KEY` to `getImages()`:

```
Call<Movies> call=yourRetrofitInterface.getImages(BuildConfig.TMD_API_KEY);
```

Also, your `@GET` annotation seems to be missing the path to the REST endpoint (shown in my sample as `/rest/of/your/path/here`).

Comment: The endpoint can change based on a setting that the user can toggle. My only questions relates to how this is possible when the api_key is in between the other 2 strings in my annotation, in your response you got rid of this "?api_key=", the remainder of the endpoint is my baseURL which I set in another section of my code

Comment: @tccpg288: "My only questions relates to how this is possible when the api_key is in between the other 2 strings in my annotation" -- your API key cannot be in the annotation. That is what the error is telling you: the value in the annotation must be a constant. Yours is not. "in your response you got rid of this "?api_key="" -- I moved it into the `@Query` annotation.

Comment: I am unable to pass the String I created into the Query parameter

Comment: @tccpg288: That is not valid Java syntax. I have updated my answer to clarify how you pass in your API key.

Comment: I have updated my code, the API Key is now appearing at the end of my request URL which I believe is causing the issue

Comment: @tccpg288: No, your problem is that you are not passing in the API key `getImages()`. You appear to be passing in `?api_key=...`, where `...` is the API key. Remove the `?api_key=` from the value that you are passing to `getImages()`. Just pass in the API key.

Comment: Got it - appreciated. I did not realize that the actual API Key could be at the end of the request URL - order is not important